# Retrofit with RxAndroid intigration

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, rx-android

I use Retrofit for call Restful API. I read some post of Rx Android but i am not get exact idea that how to integrate Rx Android with Retrofit in newly defined observable pattern.
I refer link come from googling. But not getting clarify how to achieve it so i want proper example or any post to learn.

Comment: Be more specific. What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: want to integrate api with Rx Android in observable pattern.

Comment: there is so much articles about that, http://randomdotnext.com/retrofit-rxjava/    https://medium.com/@ahmedrizwan/rxandroid-and-retrofit-2-0-66dc52725fff#.3gbm0jt58

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are switching to RxAndroid, I would suggest you start with: http://blog.danlew.net/2014/09/15/grokking-rxjava-part-1 . In the post, the author explained carefully, and there are 4 posts in the series.

Then you can read more on Retrofit2: https://realm.io/news/droidcon-jake-wharton-simple-http-retrofit-2/ ; there are examples with Call, Observable, and Future.

From the simple hello world of using Observable to get desire output from onNext (similar to a Callback):

> ```
> Observable<String> myObservable = Observable.create(
>     new Observable.OnSubscribe<String>() {
>         @Override
>         public void call(Subscriber<? super String> sub) {
>             sub.onNext("Hello, world!");
>             sub.onCompleted();
>         }
>     }
> );
>
> Subscriber<String> mySubscriber = new Subscriber<String>() {
>     @Override
>     public void onNext(String s) { System.out.println(s); }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCompleted() { }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onError(Throwable e) { }
> };
>
> myObservable.subscribe(mySubscriber);
> // Outputs "Hello, world!"
> ```

We can then implement Retrofit2 something like this:

> ```
> interface GitHubService {
>   @GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
>   Observable<List<Contributor>> repoContributors(
>       @Path("owner") String owner,
>       @Path("repo") String repo);
> }
>
> Subscriber<List<Contributor>> repoSubscriber = new Subscriber<List<Contributor>>() {
>     @Override
>     public void onNext(List<Contributor> list) { 
>
>          // do something with the list 
>     }
>
>
>     @Override
>     public void onCompleted() { }
>
>     @Override
>     public void onError(Throwable e) { }
> };
>
> gitHubService.repoContributors("square", "retrofit")
>     .subscribe(repoSubscriber);
> ```

You can use Action1 as well as a subscriber.

> ```
> gitHubService.repoContributors("square", "retrofit")
>     .subscribe(new Action1<List<Contributor>>() {
>       @Override public void call(List<Contributor> contributors) {
>         // ...
>       }
>     });
> ```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11509555)

Comment: I edited my answer. Thank you.